# PyQt5 how to make changes to second window when first window closes

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am relatively new to GUI design, what I want is very simple:

Suppose I have two windows , when first window closes, it will change the label text on second window.

any help will be appreciated! thanks

Comment: have you attempted anything yourself? Edit what you achieved with your code.

Comment: show your code please

Comment: code shown below

Comment: Is that an answer or is it just your code?

Comment: that's an answer, it worked already

Answer (score -1):

I just made it work myself, the basic idea is to pass one window object to the other window for modification.

For example, when window2 closes, I will make change to window1:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

class window_1(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    #Initilization stuff
    def __init__(self):
        super(window_1,self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,500,500)
        self.Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.Label.setGeometry(100,100,200,10)
        self.Label.setText('Second Window Not closed yet')
        self.show()


class window_2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    #Pass win1 object during initialization
    def __init__(self,win1_obj):
        super(window_2,self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(600,50,500,500)
        self.win1_obj = win1_obj
        self.show()

    #Define what happens when window2 closes
    def closeEvent(self,event):
        self.win1_obj.Label.setText('Second Window closed!')



app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
win1 = window_1() #window1 object
win2 = window_2(win1) #pass window1 object to window2 class
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```